# Is dataframe.orderBy(rand) the same as dataframe.withColumn("X",rand).orderBy("X")

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I understand that [`rand()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) produces a column with random values and [`orderBy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) takes in a column to sort either in descending or ascending order.

Looking at `dataframe.orderBy(rand)`:

I find it puzzling that `orderBy` can take in a column and sort, even though it has not been created on `dataframe`.

Compared to

```
dataframe.withColumn("X",rand).orderBy("X")
```

where `dataframe("X")` is already defined.

Which leads me to two questions.

1. Is `dataframe.orderBy(rand)` the same as `dataframe.withColumn("X",rand).orderBy("X")` in context of ordering?
2. Is it necessary to create additional columns for the purpose of ordering before using `.orderBy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both variants are equivalent, and are that surprising. `orderBy` takes expression or a name of the column. Here it is the first variant. If you're familiar with SQL,

```
dataframe.withColumn("X",rand).orderBy("X")
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, randr AS X FROM table) ORDER BY X
```

while

```
dataframe.orderBy(rand)
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY randr
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to where I could learn more about about the expressions that you wrote? Also thanks for the answer!